# Date calculation in linux

Tags: linux, shell-scripting

In linux how to get the date of the first day of the week monday.

I know that date +"%u" gives the current day of the week from this how to get the date of the monday of that week

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `date` command is very flexible about the input it will take from `-d` Try this

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $(date +%u) -eq "1" ]
then
   date
else
   date -d "last monday"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
date --date="Monday"
```

to get the date of this Monday. You can also do

```
date --date="next Monday"
```

to get the date of the next Monday. You can also use "last Monday" to get the date of the previous Monday.

Refer to the Man pages for more details.